# Calling a constructor with arguments from another constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, arguments

I'm trying to call the constructor of class B from class A by passing some arguments (args1,args2). I am using something like this:

```
public class A
{
       private readonly B _b;
       public A()
       {
         _b=new B(TypeA args1,TypeB args2);
       }

...
}

public class B
{

   public B(TypeA  new_args1,TypeB new_args2)
   {
     ...
   }

...
}
```

But from what I see in debug althougth args1 and args2 have the correct values that I want to send, new_args1 and new_args2 do not change. Is there a specific syntax I have to use to do that?

Comment: `new B(args1, args2)` will pass `args1` and `args2` to `B`'s constructor. Please show the actual code that fails.

Comment: This is not possible considering code you've provided, please provide full source code of both constructors

Comment: @Itison: It does not matter that _b is readonly because it is being initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @Eric J. Yes, but he said the variables do not change. So I figured he was probably attempting to change these variables in some other part of the code.

Comment: @Itison: Ah, maybe.  I see where you're coming from.

Comment: What do you mean by "new_args1 and new_args2 do not change"? Are you attempting to change them after declaring them? If so, I don't think that would work because you've declared _b as readonly. Otherwise, please post more code.

Comment: Thanks all for your time,first of all.
What i mean by "new_args1 and new_args2 do not change" is that they do not get any value.args1 and args2 have values assigned to them. i want to pass them to B and use them,but i added a watch on  new_args1,new_args2 and i see that they remain null.indeed after passing them i intend to change them but i was goimg to assign them to some dependency properties to do so.But i'm stuck to this earlier point for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you call the args to the constructor of B "new".  They are *the* arguments for instantiating that particular object instance.

Except for the fact that you're missing a type in the argument declaration, your code looks correct.  What *exactly* is wrong.

```
public B(new_args1,new_args2)
```

is missing the types, e.g.

```
public B(int new_args1, int new_args2)
```

Given the type assumption above

```
_b=new B(42, 24);
```

would cause B to be initialized as

```
public B(int new_args1, int new_args2)
{
    // new_args1 has the value 42
    // new_args2 has the value 24
}
```

Assuming you assign those values somewhere in B, e.g.

```
public class B 
{
    public int A1 { get; private set; }
    public int A2 { get; private set; }
    public B(int new_args1, int new_args2)
    {
        // new_args1 has the value 42
        A1 = new_args1;
        // new_args2 has the value 24
        A2 = new_args2;
    }
}
```

then

```
_b.A1
```

would have the value 42, and

```
_b.A2
```

would have the value 24

after you initialize _b.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm trying to do,pass them and then asssign them to A1,A2.But from what  i saw watching their values when the code was being executed, i got args1=42,args2=24,new_args1=null,new_args2=null.As a result A1=null,A2=null as well.And i was wondering if there is some other logic i should follow,like linking the classes as well somehow.I thougth where it could be a problem that instead of _b=new B(42, 24), i'm using _b=new B(dp1, dp2) where dp1,dp2 are dependency properties who take a value from user, but i dont think it is since watching them i see they have the values i want.

Comment: The approach I have outlined is certainly correct.  Perhaps post a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: thanks for your help,i found that i hadn't implemented correctly the logic that you outlined.i was trying to call the A constructor from within the A class again and the args were losing their values.Anyway what you said is correct,so i'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's fix syntax:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly B _b;
    public A(TypeA args1, TypeB args2)
    {
        _b = new B(args1, args2);
    }

}

public class B
{
    public B(TypeA new_args1, TypeB new_args2)
    {

    }

}
```

Please note that types of arguments must match exactly otherwise another constructor with matching signature may be invoked. Let's say yo have two constructors on `B` in this case the first one gets invoked and the second one not:

```
public class B
{
    public B(TypeA new_args1, TypeB new_args2)
    {

    }

    public B(TypeA new_args1, TypeC new_args2)
    {

    }

}
```

---

One more point: I would youse DI (**Dependency Injection**) in this case. Doing construction in constructor is a flaw unless a constructed object is an atomic data structure like `List`, `Dictionary` etc.

```
public class M
{
    public void Main(TypeA new_args1, TypeB new_args2)
    {
        var b = new B(new_args1, new_args2);
        var a = new A(b);
    }
}


public class A
{
    private readonly B _b;
    public A(B b)
    {
        _b = _b;
    }

}

public class B
{
    public B(TypeA new_args1, TypeB new_args2)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the syntax in the question,sorry for that.As for the DI i'm not familiar with it and i'll look it up(if you can give me something to read,you re most welcome).However in your code i dont see where you pass the values of args1,arsg2.You only used new_args1 and new_args2.

Answer (score 0):

Well what i can see the error in your code is that you should declare your A constructor with paranthesis i.e. A() and check whether it works. Beside that your code looks absolutely correct.

Comment: No,thanks but thats not it,it's just a typo.I'll edit it on my question though to avoid the misunderstanting.